# How to store transaction data in dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have two transactions: Transfer & Purchase. I want that the purchase transaction to be stored only, if the Transfer transaction is stored.

If the api fails to store the Purchase transaction then the Transfer transaction should be deleted.

How to achieve this in dynamodb using nodejs?

Comment: Assuming you're using promises couldn't you throw an error if the purchase fails to store. In the catch block you can then return a promise to delete the transfer if it's an expected error and continue down the chain or throw if it isn't an expected error.

Comment: that's what I did but is there a more elegant method?

Comment: If your average case is both of them succeeding you could save them both in parallel using Promise.all() then if there's an error go back and delete the transfer. That means your database requests aren't blocking.

Comment: but if the delete call fails (in case of api gateway timeout), then one of the transactions still remains in the database.